# Shuffle / Sort JS Array based on distribution

Tags: javascript, sorting, shuffle

I am not sure if this is possible, or how it would work for large arrays.

If I have an array of generated text output

- This is a Monday
- This is a Tuesday
- Hello World
- Hi World
- This is a Friday

Is there a way where I can shuffle them randomly and  maximise the distance between similar items, i.e. for the list above a 'good' output would be

- This is a Friday
- Hello World
- This is a Tuesday
- Hi World
- This is a Monday

I am thinking it could be as basic as mapping each element's length, but I don't know how I can then sort them to be as far away from another similar length item.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have only tried a random shuffle with the Fisher-Yates algo https://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/

Comment: I guess "shuffle randomly" and "maximise the distance" contradict each other. Do you want to shuffle it, or do you want to maximise the distance? ;)

Comment: I know "yes" isn't a valid answer :) It's a sort of weighted shuffle or something. It might be the daftest idea ever, or just a case of not knowing the concise question.

I suppose by maximising the distance it would shuffle them, so probably that's the goal